# Software to upmix stereo to 5.1

Tags: audio, 5.1, mixing

I used a [Creative USB SoundBlaster Live External](http://www.soundblaster.com/products/product.asp?category=1&product=10702) soundcard before

The soundcard had a feature called CMSS® 3D2 described on the website as

"Enjoy virtual surround sound on stereo speakers/headphones"

Now I have a new pc which has integrated 5.1 soundcard from Realtek.

[image: new system configuration]

Is there any software able to achieve similar things? Not necessarily a plugin since I would like to use it with Spotify not only Winamp and such.

Comment: What motherboard model do you have and what's the OS version?

Comment: my system config is the following http://imgur.com/gsJks.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Realtek HD Audio Manager has Speaker Fill and Virtual Surround options. See the [manual](http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/FileList/NewTech/2006_motherboard_newtech/hd_audio_driver_usermanualver1-00_0418-05.pdf).

You can enable Speaker Fill here:

[image: setting screenshot]